# How to reroute console.log to document.write

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a "Console" app for JavaScript so that messages are written to the screen.

```
console.log("Rerouting log messages to the screen");
console.log = function (message) { document.writeln(message); };
console.log("Log messages are now routed to the screen.");
```

This works, except that each time something is written to the screen, it wipes out any existing content.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `document.write` works. To avoid this you should use `document.createElement` and `document.body.appendChild` for example.

For example you can try this code:

```
console.log = function (message) { 
    var p = document.createElement( 'p' );
    p.innerHTML = message;
    document.body.appendChild( p );
};
```

Read more about [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) at MDN.

Comment: Great, thanks very much.  Will accept when it lets me.